# c++ - automatic casting with derived class

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have a class called `Action`, and a `MoveAction` which derives from `Action` and I have an object which holds a variable: `Action action_to_perform`. Now I assigned a new MoveAction to this variable. These Action classes holds a method `perform()`. `MoveAction` does something else than `Action`'s perform. When I call

```
object->action_to_perform
```

then it calls Action's perform method, when it's set to a MoveAction object. How can I automatically cast it a MoveAction?

EDIT:

Action.h:

```
class Action
{
public:
    Action();
    virtual ~Action();

    virtual void perform();
protected:
private:
};
```

MoveAction.h:

```
class MoveAction : public Action
{
public:
    MoveAction(int, int);
    virtual ~MoveAction();

    int dx, dy;

    virtual void perform();
protected:
private:
};
```

In Player.cpp:

```
Action action_to_perform;
...
action_to_perform = MoveAction(0, 1);
```

Comment: Have you declared the function virtual? Show some code

Comment: Yea, perform is declared as virtual. I added some code that shows what I meant

Comment: Use pointers to action if you want to preserve virtual behaviour - what you did is truly slicing, your `action_to_perform = MoveAction(0,1)` is actually using `Action::operator = (const Action&)` which slices the object - VMT of Action, not of MoveAction)

Comment: To help avoid doing this, make Action pure virtual. Declare perform as `virtual void perform() = 0;`

Comment: Duplicate of [what is the slicing problem in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c). Reopened for some strange reason.

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing the problem of [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

You need to store a pointer to `Action`.

```
Action* action_to_perform = NULL;
...
action_to_perform = new MoveAction(0, 1);
action_to_perform->perform();
```

should work.

To simplify memory management, it is better to store a smart pointer, such as `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

```
std::unique_ptr<Action> action_to_perform;
...
action_to_perform.reset(new MoveAction(0, 1));
action_to_perform->perform();
```

Comment: References also work, though not in the OPs specific use case.  I'd also suggest the use of some type of smart pointer (`shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, etc.)